# SDK Platform Tools component missing - Similar to Android Eve below

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

Ubuntu Linux 10.04//Eclipse 3.5.2

I'm new to Eclipse and Android. Eclipse is up and running simple Jave apps OK.  I moved on to downloading the Android SDK starter package, which seemed to go OK.  Ran the SDK manager and downladed Platforms 7,8 & 9.  Installed the ADT package in Eclipse.

I've tried to load the SDK path into the Eclipse Preferences, but it won't retain the path.  After restart, Elipse says it can't find SDK package.  Also,one message said that the (revision?) number of the ADT couldn't be found.

I've reinstalled Eclipse a couple of times, and then gone through the SDK & ADT download procedures a couple of times and am stuck.  Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Hertfordkc

**Stupid question caused by not thoroughly reading the Android Developers Guide and the tutorials before trying to start a project.  Don't know why I didn't get a message about a missing XML file.**

Comment: just a thought, try deleting the `.metadata` folder in your workspace folder

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, I don't see a .metadata folder or file in my workspace folder. I did the reinstalls thinking that maybe I fat fingered a path or filename, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Might I have created a corrupted .ini file in one of my earlier tries?  If so, where would I find it?  I'm using Linux.